# Проблема с циклом в Python 2.7

Tags: python, циклы, list

```
for i in range(count):
        p.append(jdata['response'][i]['id'])
```

Выдаёт ошибку:

```
'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Как решить проблему? Python 2.7

jdata получен таким образом:

```
jdata = json.loads(data)
```

Я просто не могу понять почему

```
p.append(jdata['response'][1]['id'])
```

работает, а

```
p.append(jdata['response'][i]['id'])
```

нет.

Comment: строка

    p.append(jdata['response'][i]['id'])

на самом деле выглядит так

    p.append(jdata.__getitem__('response').__getitem__(i).__getitem__('id'))

А у Вас один с объектов им не является, а является обычным целым. Понятно, что целое не может быть массивом.


То есть, ошибку следует читать так "ожидался массив, но оказалось целое". А вот в каком из трех вариантов - это нужно смотеть отдельно - разбейте на части, будет понятно.

Answer (score 1):

Я понимаю, что это жуткий костыль, но другого пути я не знаю, решил проблему так:

```
for i in range(count):
    p.append(jdata['response'][1+i]['id'])
```

Comment: Скорее всего именно у нулевого элемента и не получается взять id. Как вариант можно задать номер начального элемента в range: range(1,count).

Вообще, если нужны все элементы jdata['response'], то более по-питоновски было бы сделать

    for item in jdata['response'].

Comment: Да, вы оказались правы, именно нулевой элемент и не имел id. Ошибка восьмиклассника)

Answer (score 0):

Кода маловато так что сказать точно сложно. Возможно count великоват и происходит выход за границы.

Можно ли кусок побольше? А еще лучше добавить содержимое данных которые передаете в массив.